# How to pass data back to an interface controller in Watchkit

Tags: swift, delegates, watchkit, pass-data, wkinterfacecontroller

I know that this question has been asked a lot but it seems that nobody has given a proper answer.

I have an interface controller that has a table. Now when the user selects a a row I push the information to a new interface controller `self.pushController(withName: "DetailInterfaceController", context: context)` . Now in the new DetailInterfaceController I can access my context very easily in `awake(withContext context: Any?)` . So far so good. The user is supposed to change something in the context and then send the context back to the previous interface controller. I use the delegate pattern to do it. I thought that I could use it as in the ios. But I encounter the problem of the delegate. I can not find a way to set the delegate. Watchkit does not allow you to just create an instance of an interface controller (the way I would normally do it in ios).

I tried:

https://makeapppie.com/2015/05/29/swift-watchkit-introducing-navigation-to-the-apple-watchpart-4-dismissals-and-segues/

and this:

http://koreyhinton.com/blog/watchkit-delegates-and-contexts.html

but I have an error from the compiler that I can not downcast my context.

I just can not believe it that there is no way in watch kit to set the delegate! It seems absurd. I use delegate pattern a lot in ios.

Can somebody tell me a way that this can be done? Or it simply can not be done in Watchkit?

Answer (score 0):

you could use Notifications with NotificationCenter to pass around the data, if the suggested solutions in the links did not work for you.